# How to determine if posting JSON with PHP cURL is succeed?

Tags: php, json, laravel, curl, laravel-4

### Goal

I want to know if I post my JSON successfully to this url `http://localhost/api_v2/url/post?key=***`, so I can retrieve them back eventually, but I am not sure, how I would test them.

### I tried

Normally, we can just `print_r($result )` to see what is in the variable, but when I did that nothing showed up.

When I do `echo $result` also nothing showed up.

So far, nothing help, so I decide to move up an next variable `$ch` when I do `echo $ch;` I got this `Resource id #188`. Now, I am stuck.

Can someone help me clarify on this ?

### Here is my code

```
public function post(){

    $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/api_v2/url?key=***");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $file_name = 'inventory.csv';
    $file_path = 'C:\\QuickBooks\\'.$file_name;
    $csv= file_get_contents($file_path);
    $utf8_csv = utf8_encode($csv);
    $array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $utf8_csv));
    $json = json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))                                                                       
    );  

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('data' => $json));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if($status == 200){
        echo "Post Successfully!";
    }
}
```

### ( Updated )

Here is my routes

```
// API Version 2 
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api_v2'), function(){
    Route::post('url/post', array('before' => 'api_v2', 'uses' => 'UrlController@post'));
    Route::get('url/reveive', array('before' => 'api_v2', 'uses' => 'UrlController@receive'));
    Route::get('url/store', array('before' => 'api_v2', 'uses' => 'UrlController@store'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the returned HTTP status code to determine if the request was successful:

```
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($status == 200){
   echo "Post Successfully!";
}
```

---

I also think something isn't working quite right since the `dd($result)` shows a 404 page. Probably there's no route matching `POST http://localhost/api_v2/url?key=***`

### Edit

I'm not the curl expert but as far as I know you should pass that data as an array:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('data' => $json));
```

On the other end you can retrieve it like that:

```
$data = json_decode(Input::get('data'));
```

### Edit 2

To use the CSRF filter on a single route:

```
Route::post('url/post', array('before' => 'csrf|api_v2', 'uses' => 'UrlController@post'));
```

Or alternatively using CSRF for a certain HTTP verb (and prefix if you want)

```
Route::when('*', 'csrf', array('post'));
```

Comment: Allow me to do `dd($result)` again. I will tell you the outcome, but thaks for your answer, so far I got `Post Successfully!`

Comment: According to ` Route::get('url/post', array('before' => 'api_v2', 'uses' => 'UrlController@post'));` - should I replace `Route::get` with `Route::post` - what is your thought on that ?

Comment: Yes definitely. Also if you still make the request to `http://localhost/api_v2/url?key=***` you need to remove the `post` segment from the route url.

Comment: Ok- I will take it off. Do you mind tell me how to retrieve what I just posted ? IMO - I think that is the way to tell if you post it right is to **receive what you posted** Don't you think so ?

Comment: I throw `$data = json_decode(Input::get('data'));` in my other function called `receive`, and when I go to this `http://localhost/api_v2/url/receive?key=***` I got 404.

Comment: Attention, if you enter the URL in your browser you are making a GET request. There are tools and browser extensions to simulate POST and other requests...

Comment: But I went to the `receive` one which should be `get` - Please correct me if I am wrong. About the browser extension, I am using postman on Chrome.

Comment: Hmm. Could you update your question with your current routes? I'm a bit confused at the moment..

Comment: Hmm yes. `GET http://localhost/api_v2/url/receive?key=***` should work according to your routes. I honestly have no idea what the problem could be...

Comment: My dummy typo `reveive` !!!  It's work now, it should be `receive`. Thanks again for your help Lukas. You're awesome as always !

Comment: When I used Postman to test, I entered this url `http://localhost/api_v2/url/post?key=***` - and set the verb to POST - then I got `Illuminate \ Session \ TokenMismatchException` Do you know why ?

Comment: Do you use the CSRF filter? Because that's what would produce such an error.

Comment: Hi @lukasgeiter, I set up the CSRF for all routes in my application. Is there a way to set up **only** for one route which is this one = http://localhost/api_v2/url/post?key=***

Comment: Follow your Edit 2, I did this `Route::post('url/post', array('before' => 'csrf|api_v2', 'uses' => 'UrlController@post'));` still get the same error. `"Illuminate \ Session \ TokenMismatchException"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70049/discussion-between-evoque2015-and-lukasgeiter).